# How to add an external folder with header files (include folder) to a Visual Studio project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sierrachart

I have a main.cpp file that relies on a header file located in another location.

```
#include "C:\SierraChart\ACS_Source\sierrachart.h"
```

My project is in `C:\dev\`

I don't want to specify an explicit path in the include directive, is it possible to add that absolute path as an additional include directory?

so I can just use:

```
#include "sierrachart.h"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add it in

`Project > Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories`

Comment: It says in the documentation that I should do: `C:\SierraChart\ACS_Source;%(IncludePath)` But I'm not sure about the syntax.

Comment: My bad. I was doing `#include "<sierrachart.h>"`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar kind of issue, where I have added the path in the "Additional Include Directories", but then it still it says cannot open the source file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).